# Spring Integration jms aysnchronous request/reply

Tags: asynchronous, jms, spring-integration

We have a requirement to service the GUI with a SI service. The GUI communicates with the backend over JMS queues, and will wait for a response on a tmp queue that is specified in the jms replyTo header property.

So there can be 10 gui's making queries to the backend, and receiving messages on their individual tmp queues.

So I wrote a SI service using inbound gateway that looks like this

```
<int:channel id="inChannel" />  
<int:channel id="outChannel" />

<int-jms:inbound-gateway id="jmsSampleService" request-destination-name="TEST_QUEUE_2" request-channel="inChannel" 
connection-factory="qpidJmsConnectionFactory" extract-request-payload="true" error-channel="errorChannel" /> 
<int:service-activator input-channel="inChannel" ref="sampleService2" method="processMessage" />

public class SampleService2 {

public Response processMessage(Object obj) throws Exception {
    LOG.info("Message received on sample service. ");
    Thread.sleep(5000);     
    Response response = new ResponseImpl();
    response.setPayload("Test response");
    return response;
}
```

This works fine, i can see the service return a message back on the jmsReplyTo queue. However, this is a single threaded synchronous operation which means unless GUI1 was serviced, GUI2 's call will be blocked. I want to do this asynchronously since this is simply a method call on a class.

We were doing something similar in mule

```
<flow name="sampleServiceFlow">
  <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="TEST_QUEUE" connector-ref="queryQpidConnector" />                    
  <byte-array-to-object-transformer />
  <component>
      <spring-object bean="sampleService" />
  </component>
  <object-to-byte-array-transformer />
  <expression-filter evaluator="groovy"
        expression="message.getOutboundProperty('replyToQueueName') != null" />
  <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="#[header:OUTBOUND:replyToQueueName]" connector-ref="queryQpidConnector" />             
</flow>
```

Since the mule service does not have any txns, it is able to simply consume a message in auto-ack, and have the SampleService's method call service the call.

Is there a way of implementing something like this in SI? perhaps by using the message-driven-channel-adapter? Is there a way to propagate jms header properties between channels?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use concurrency on the inbound gateway. `concurrent-consumers` is the min `max-concurrent-consumers` (if specified) is the max; the adapter's container with adjust the concurrency depending on demand.

I am not sure what you mean by

> Is there a way to propagate jms header properties between channels?

The jms headers are mapped to integration headers and vice-versa.